# Applying virtual function on a struct

Tags: c++

is it possible to say virtual struct somefunction() = 0 ?

is possible to apply virtual functions on a struct ? if its possible what would be the definition for it, an example would be appreciated.

I have the following case

```
private:
    VarField(Type type);
    Type _type;
    union
    {
        unsigned int uintVal;
        double dblVal;
        char* strVal;
    } _val;
```

and I would like to add a struct to that class

however I need a pure virtual function that this class implements. 
but it should override a struct.

Comment: You will need to be more specific. Hard to know what you're asking.

Comment: @NikBougalis I would like to override a function that returns a struct. eg. virtual struct GetGeom() = 0;

Comment: @andreahmed Then you write the name of the type like in the function you're overriding, not "struct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to say virtual struct somefunction() = 0 ?

No. That is not syntactically correct.

> is possible to apply virtual functions on a struct ?

Yes. All (non-union) classes can have virtual functions, whether they were declared with the `struct` keyword or not.

> an example would be appreciated.

Here is an example of a pure virtual function:

```
struct S {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Comment: so its not possible to say virtual struct somefunction() = 0

Comment: @andreahmed No. Just like its not possible to declare a function like `struct somefunction();` The syntax requires that before the name of the function, there is a type name (the return type). `struct` is not a type name, it is a keyword.